# grant insert,update,delete on synonym to user

Tags: oracle

I am trying to give grant privilege on a synonym to a user. I am getting the below error :

grant select, insert, delete, update on SYNONYM to USER;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid

I tried recreating the synonyms, but that too didnt work. Deleted and created fresh tables, still its not working.
Is it that we cant grant insert,update,delete privileges on synonym?

Comment: try to use synonym name instead of "synonym"

Comment: can u check the synonym is created for a valid object?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Oracle docs note on this :

```
ORA-00980 synonym translation is no longer valid

Cause: The synonym used is based on a table, view, or synonym that no longer exists.

Action: Replace the synonym with the name of the object it references or 
        re-create the synonym so that it refers to a valid table, view, or synonym.
```

**Some of the reasons are :**

1. You created a synonym on non-existing object by mistake. For example, you created a synonym on SCOTT.DEPT where either the SCOTT schema in not present or the DEPT table is missing.
2. You dropped an object but you did not drop the synonyms referencing the object.
3. You dropped a user, but you did not drop synonyms referencing the objects owned by that user.

Keep in mind when reviewing your ORA-00980 situation that as objects become dropped the synonyms are not dropped and they remain until explicitly dropped.

**Reference** : http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00980_synonym_translation_is_no_longer_valid.htm